# How to resolve the error dataframe not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
Count = df.groupby("user_id", as_index=False).count()
Mean = df.groupby("user_id", as_index=False).mean()

dfMerged = pd.merge(df, count, how='right', on=['user_id'])
dfMerged()
```

Comment: You can't call `dfMerged()` like a function.

Comment: Please remove the open and close parenthesis after `dfMerged`, dfMerged is a dataframe not a function/method and hence not callable

Answer (score -1):

`dfMerged` is not a function.
When you create like this:

```
def dfMerged():
        print('This is function')

dfMerged() #Result -- this is a function
```

Then it's a function.

```
Count = df.groupby("user_id", as_index=False).count()
Mean = df.groupby("user_id", as_index=False).mean()

dfMerged = pd.merge(df, count, how='right', on=['user_id'])
dfMerged.head(10)
```